# Azure Application Insights and NLog

Tags: azure, nlog, azure-application-insights

If I use NLog with the Adapter for Azure Application Insights, how do I send properties?

When I am browsing through these logs in VS or the Azure Portal I'd like to be able to group or filter them.

Is there a way to name them? Or to pass some properties or metrics?

Answer (score 4):

Custom properties support was added when resolving this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-logging/issues/5
If you check pull request for this issue you can see how it is tested with a unit test:

```
Logger aiLogger = this.CreateTargetWithGivenInstrumentationKey();
var eventInfo = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Trace, "TestLogger", "Hello!");  
eventInfo.Properties["Name"] = "Value";  
aiLogger.Log(eventInfo);
```

When you look at the details blade for that trace message you will find "Name" property there.

Comment: If you want to do this at a global level, use `Logger.Properties` (and the `SetProperties` method)